# Trouble handling QClipboard::dataChanged() signal

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a Qt app that monitors changes to the system clipboard. Every time the user copies some text to the clipboard (outside the application), my app is supposed to change that text somehow and copy the changed text to the clipboard.

The problem is that the clipboard only becomes empty!

Here's my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()), 
            this, SLOT(processClipboardChange()));
}

void MainWindow::processClipboardChange()
{
    qDebug() << "dataChanged() signal emitted.";

    QClipboard * clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();

    static bool dontProcessSignal = false;

    if (!dontProcessSignal) {

        QString text = clipboard->text();
        text = "CLIPBOARD CONTENTS CHANGED."; // example.

        qDebug() << "Setting clipboard contents...";
        dontProcessSignal = true;
        clipboard->setText(text); // will trigger another dataChanged() signal.
        dontProcessSignal = false;
        qDebug() << "Copied " << clipboard->text() << " to clipboard.";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Did not process dataChanged() signal.";
        return;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the program, and change the clipboard contents by copying some text with Ctrl+C, I get this output:

```
dataChanged() signal emitted.
Setting clipboard contents...
dataChanged() signal emitted.
Did not process dataChanged() signal.
Copied  "CLIPBOARD CONTENTS CHANGED."  to clipboard.
```

But when I type Ctrl+V to paste the clipboard contents somewhere, nothing gets pasted. It seems that the clipboard contents are set to an empty string for some reason.

`QClipboard::setText()` works just fine in other code (e.g. when called inside a `QPushButton::clicked` slot).

I'm at a loss. Please help.

Comment: What you you try to call `clipboard->setText(text, QClipboard::Selection);` too after `clipboard->setText(text);`? Does it make any difference in behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Qt deletes the clipboard data if you mess with setText() inside dataChanged(). It doesn't delete the clipboard if you copy inside the application itself. You can use QTimer or invokeMethod with QueuedConnection to solve this:

```
void MainWindow::processClipboardChange()
{
  if (!dontProcessSignal) {
    // Solution 1, unable to pass argument
    QTimer::singleShot(1, this, SLOT(setClipboard1()));

    // Solution 2, able to pass argument
    QString newText = "CLIPBOARD CONTENTS CHANGED.";
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "setClipboard2", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, newText)); 
  }
}
void MainWindow::setClipboard1() {
  dontProcessSignal = true;
  QClipboard * clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
  clipboard->setText("CLIPBOARD CONTENTS CHANGED.");
  dontProcessSignal = false;
}
void MainWindow::setClipboard2(QString s) {
  dontProcessSignal = true;
  QClipboard * clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
  clipboard->setText(s);
  dontProcessSignal = false;
}
```

Comment: In case you're wondering why you get a `No such method`error: `setClipboard2` needs to be a Slot

Comment: Can't get this to work, causes infinite loop despite the flag (always false in Slot).

Answer (score 3):

I successfully used the `QTimer` approach described above by fxam to solve the problem.

Here's all of my code for future readers:

`mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void clipboardChanged();
    void setClipboard();

private:
    QString clipboardText;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QClipboard>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QRegularExpression>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()),
            this, SLOT(clipboardChanged()));
}

void MainWindow::clipboardChanged()
{
    // we need to ignore every other dataChanged() signal because
    // those signals are triggered by us calling QClipboard::setText()
    static bool ignoreSignal = false;

    if (ignoreSignal == false) {
        clipboardText = QApplication::clipboard()->text();

        // will trigger another dataChanged() signal
        // (after our method exits)
        QTimer::singleShot(50, this, SLOT(setClipboard()));

        // ignore the next dataChanged() signal
        ignoreSignal = true;
    }
    else {
        // We're ignoring this signal. Don't ignore the next signal.
        ignoreSignal = false;
    }
}

void MainWindow::setClipboard()
{
    static QRegularExpression regex("x+"); // example...
    static QString replacement("a");
    QString newClipboardText = clipboardText.replace(regex, replacement);
    QApplication::clipboard()->setText(newClipboardText);
}
```